# Cannot change control name property in IDE (VB.Net 2008 and ActiveReports.)

Tags: vb.net, ide, activereports

I have a VB.Net 2008 project that use ActiveReports.  The problem is that any control on the report does not list the control's Name in the Properties window.  All other properties seem to be there, just not the Name.  The only way to change the name is to go into the forms .vb and change the name with a search and replace (like Me.Label1 to Me.lblAmount).  All other forms are fine, it's just the ActiveReports forms. This happened just recently and there didn't seem to be any sort of update/event that triggered it.  Anyone else have this issue before?
Thanks in advance,
-J

Answer (score 1):

It is suggested that you download and upgrade to the most recent available build/service pack of the version of ActiveReports you are working with. And thereafter you should not face an issues.

The latest service packs can be downloaded from the following links :

AR3 : http://www.datadynamics.com/forums/121331/ShowPost.aspx

AR6 : http://www.datadynamics.com/forums/83/ShowForum.aspx

AR7 : http://our.componentone.com/groups/topic/activereports-7-service-pack-1-maintenance-release-now-available-2/

After the download, make sure that all of the dll’s of the upgraded version are present in the GAC. Also check that there isn't any dll of the previous version is present in GAC. After that remove all the ActiveReports references and then re-add the latest dll(s) in your project. Re-build the whole solution. You may also try creating a new project and check whether the name property appears.

Regards,
Mohita